# using BeautifulSoup to print images from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm practicing using BeautifulSoup in python, trying to parse information from this website:

https://www.vogue.com/fashion/street-style

how would you print images from the website? for example I tried to parse the logo which exists here in the HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.vogue.com/fashion/street-style').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

logo = soup.find('img', class_='logo--image')
print(logo)
```

this prints out:

```
<img alt="Vogue Logo" class="logo--image" src="/img/vogue-logo-pride.svg"/>
```

How do I print the actual picture in my editor?

Comment: By print, do you mean preview the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick Summary

Unfortunately, modern editors/terminals support *text*, not images. There are some alternatives:

- Option 1: Download the image and open it regularly.
- Option 2: Open a new browser tab with the image.

## Solution

#### Option 1

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import shutil

WEBSITE = 'https://www.vogue.com/fashion/street-style'
SAVE_LOCATION = 'downloaded.svg'  # name of file to save image to

source = requests.get(WEBSITE).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

relative_link_to_logo = soup.find('img', class_='logo--image')['src']

img = requests.get(f'{WEBSITE}/{relative_link_to_logo}', stream=True)
with open(SAVE_LOCATION,'wb') as f:
    for chunk in img:
        f.write(chunk)
```

#### Option 2

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser

WEBSITE = 'https://www.vogue.com/fashion/street-style'

source = requests.get(WEBSITE).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

relative_link_to_logo = soup.find('img', class_='logo--image')['src']

webbrowser.open(f'{WEBSITE}/{relative_link_to_logo}')
```

## Final Remarks

Some editors like Visual Studio Code have plugins that let you preview an image file (that you've downloaded to your computer) without leaving the editor. This still involves **Option 1**, downloading to disk.

I hope this helps you!